# Simplifying a fractional summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, fractions

I'm trying to simplify the following:

$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{(2i-1)(2i+1)}$

into

$\frac{n}{2n+1}$

How should I proceed?

Comment: Hint: Telescopic sums.
$$\frac{1}{(2i-1)(2i+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2i-1} - \frac{1}{2i+1}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$\frac1{(2i-1)(2i+1)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{2i-1}-\frac1{2i+1}\right)$$

This gives us the following telescoping series:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{(2i-1)(2i+1)}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac12\left(\frac1{2i-1}-\frac1{2i+1}\right)=\frac12\left(1-\frac1{2n+1}\right)=\frac n{2n+1}$$